# How do I disable SSH on boot?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Each time, after logging in, I am asked for the SSH passphrase. I would like to disable SSH on boot, just to use it when I actually need and I have tried different things, but nothing have worked so far.

Comment: On each login? SSH is used to login from a machine to another. Can you explain better what happens?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I start the PC and after asking me user and password, it asks for the SSH passphrase.

Comment: Does it happens only at the first login or even each time you open a new shell? Did you connect in a text or graphical environment? After that you logged and insert the password the first time what happens if you press CTRL+ALT+F2 and you log again? Do you work on the PC on which you log or you work on a different computer via that PC?

Comment: I am using a text environment. It asks for the passphrase only the first time. I am working on the PC I log in.

Comment: Try to press `ctrl z` when it asks for the ssh password, and see where are you (in which script). PS>Did you recently generate ssh key to do automatic login via ssh to remote computers? Because if you did you might need to give a password now to access your private key file, but you should not need to give the password to ssh.

Comment: A bit late, but I was trying to figure out which script was asking for the passphrase. Yes, I recently generated the ssh keys to login to remote computers, but I did not set it to do it automatically. One week ago I was booting loading directly the GUI and there was no need for the passphrase after the log in. The problem came out now with the text environment.

Comment: I find one bug for Ubuntu 13.10 [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-ssh/+bug/1247169). I don't know if it affects the 12.04 server too.
If forced you can use `ssh-keygen -p` to change password and put an empty one...

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep it for security reason. I would just like it not to ask me for the password all the time. I need to run an application without using the keyboard and this problem is making my life really hard.

Comment: Have you listen about `ssh-agent` or `gpg-agent`? 
Is the system updated? Last should be Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS... Extreme: what about [Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) is released. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set the default runlevels to on

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh enable
```

Sets all to off

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh disable # sets all to off
```

Remove the service from startup

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ssh remove
```

Reset it

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

**run this on the terminal:**

```
gnome-session-properties
```

**you will see this:**

[ssh key on ubuntu startop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJzDT.png)

then just remove the ssh key agent from the list